# Convert Javascript RegExp to work with Grep or Sed

Tags: javascript, regex, grep

I needed to grep some files on a server so I quickly hacked out and tested a regexp in a javascript console to meet my needs:

```
var regexp = /mssql_query\s*\([\"\'][a-z0-9_\s]*(_sp|usp_)/i

// want to pass
regexp.test('mssql_query ("something_sp')
regexp.test('mssql_query("exec something_sp')
regexp.test("mssql_query('something_else_sp")
regexp.test('mssql_query("_usp_sp')
regexp.test('mssql_query ("_usp_somethig')
regexp.test("mssql_query('_usp_something_else")

// want to fail
regexp.test('mssql_query ("something_s')
regexp.test('mssql_query("exec something_p')
regexp.test('mssql_query("select')
```

The expression works perfectly for all the test cases I threw at it, however I can't seem to get the expression to work with grep.
Is there a way to convert an EMCA expression to an ERE or BRE expression so I can use it with grep or sed?

I've tried tweaking it to work in grep but have failed miserably.

Comment: Why did you make a character class out of `\s`? Does not make sense.

Comment: Not sure why I had that there.

Comment: You also don't need to escape characters inside the []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep "mssql_query *([\"\'][a-z0-9_ ]*_sp\|usp_"
```

ought to do the job. It is looking for:

1. mssql_query, then
2. 0 or more spaces (that's the `" *"`), then
3. (, then " or ' (that's the `([\"\']`), then
4. 0 or more characters that are lowercase letters, numbers, underscores or spaces (that's the `[a-z0-9_ ]*`), then
5. _sp or usp_ (that's the `_sp\|usp_`)

Comment: I added a minor change and used: grep "mssql_query *([\"\'][a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*_sp\|usp_"...  
I originally used \s so that it might also match tabs, but in hindsight I don't know why there would ever be a tab there.

Comment: see my answer, just use grep with the right option, no need to change the regex you already tested. Although I guess its a bit late as you've already accepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

use egrep (alias for grep -E , using extended regular expressions).

also instead of the /i modifier use the -i flag for grep.