# Translate regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, grep

I would like to translate this JS regular expression

`^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$`

to use in grep. All phone numbers bellow match it:

```
+79261234567
89261234567
79261234567
+7 926 123 45 67
8(926)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
79261234567
(495)1234567
(495) 123 45 67
89261234567
8-926-123-45-67
8 927 1234 234
8 927 12 12 888
8 927 12 555 12
8 927 123 8 123
```

I've tried a lot of variants but no one works for me.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432379/convert-javascript-regexp-to-work-with-grep-or-sed) is possibly relevant.

Comment: This looks like a problem for which regex is well-suited.  What is your reason from wanting to move away from regex?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `grep -E '[0-9]'`

Comment: My comment is strange because grep uses a regex.  Oops

Comment: @I0_ol no.  for one, it can match `+` as the first character.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh When I copy these numbers to a text file and use `grep -E '[0-9]'` it returns every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your pattern, although a few things to consider are:

`[\- ]` should instead be `[- ]` or `[ -]`

> (in a character class `[]` escaping dash is unnecessary if it's first
>   or last).

`[\d]` will probably fail so either use `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]`

So this leaves you with:

```
grep -E "^((8|\+7)[ -]?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[ -]?)?[0-9 -]{7,10}$" file
```

or `egrep`:

```
egrep "^((8|\+7)[ -]?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[ -]?)?[0-9 -]{7,10}$" file
```